# Extjs Find and select Group records in grid GroupingSummary

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want code to find and **select** matching **Group records** in grid GroupingSummary by just entering group name in afterrender.

Please check below screenshot:

[image]

You can refer my fiddle: [SelectRecords](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cl3)

Comment: What do you want to do on "afterrender" precisely? Take a look on http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-getGroups to access group names and http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.selection.Model.html#method-select to select rows.

Comment: Thanks alot dude for giving me right direction. :)